# How was this question allowed to be submitted twice?

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[image: The question was asked at exactly the] same time, and the question ids differ by 1.

[43981782](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981782/c-class-static-member-function-calling-error)

[43981783](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43981783/c-class-static-member-function-calling-error)

Is this just the result of perhaps an "Eventual consistency" guarantee or a bug?

Comment: It's the net.  Funny stuff happens occasionally.  It's not really worth bothering with unless a particular class of funny happens often enough to be annoying.

Comment: So basically someone double clicked the button. Is that even possible? TEST: well not with the add comment button :)

Comment: It is normal lossage, they made it [no secret](https://blog.codinghorror.com/deadlocked/) that they are operating the dbase engine in fingers-crossed mode.

Comment: @Gimby: Not sure, we'd need to ask OP. If this were true, then momentarily disabling the submit button after click would solve it in the future.

Comment: I quite often manage to post double comments when traveling on the train; the mobile network gets flakey, the AJAX request never receives the server ACK and posts again, resulting in a duplicate. Perhaps something similar happened here?